# Split string column based on delimiter and convert it to dict in Pandas without loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below dataframe

```
clm1, clm2, clm3
10, a, clm4=1|clm5=5
11, b, clm4=2
```

My desired result is

```
clm1, clm2, clm4, clm5
10, a, 1, 5
11, b, 2, Nan
```

I have tried below method

```
rows = list(df.index)    

dictlist = []

    for index in rows: #loop through each row to convert clm3 to dict
        i = df.at[index, "clm3"]        

        mydict = dict(map(lambda x: x.split('='), [x for x in i.split('|') if '=' in x]))
        dictlist.append(mydict)


l=json_normalize(dictlist) #convert dict column to flat dataframe

resultdf = example.join(l).drop('clm3',axis=1)
```

This is giving me desired result but I am looking for a more efficient way to convert clm3 to dict which does not involve looping through each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two steps :

idea is to create a double split and then group by the index and unstack the values as columns

```
s = (
    df["clm3"]
    .str.split("|", expand=True)
    .stack()
    .str.split("=", expand=True)
    .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
)

final = pd.concat([df, s.groupby([s.index, s[0]])[1].sum().unstack()], axis=1).drop(
    "clm3", axis=1
)
```

---

```
print(final)
   clm1 clm2  clm4 clm5
0    10    a     1    5
1    11    b     2  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Datanovice I have multiple files like this with huge data. Is there any way i can do this stack and split in parallel for all files? Basically to improve performance.

Comment: You could concat all the dfs and then run it one go? I would ask a new question mention the size of your dataframe and the types (string, int float etc) and someone better than me will give you a quicker solution for sure @user0204

Comment: Do you mean the code in your answer is processing data-frame rows in parallel? Does it guarantee that output will be in same order as input?

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.extractall` to get your values and `unstack` to pivot them to a column for each unique value.

And `str.get_dummies` to get a column for each unique `clm`.

```
values = (
    df['clm3'].str.extractall('(=\d)')[0]
              .str.replace('=', '')
              .unstack()
              .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)

columns = df['clm3'].str.replace('=\d', '').str.get_dummies(sep='|').columns
values.columns = columns
dfnew = pd.concat([df[['clm1', 'clm2']], values], axis=1)
```

```
   clm1 clm2  0    1
0    10    a  1    5
1    11    b  2  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df11=df1.clm3.map(lambda x:"dict({})".format(x.replace('|',',')))\
    .map(eval).map(pd.Series).pipe(lambda ss:pd.concat(ss.tolist(),axis=1)).T
df1.drop("clm3",axis=1).join(df11)
```

out：

```
 clm1 clm2  clm4  clm5
0    10    a   1.0   5.0
1    11    b   2.0   NaN
```